# Constructor on type 'Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeRegistryHandle' not found

Tags: c#, .net, exception

After upgrading [Fax.NET](http://faxdotnet.codeplex.com) project to .NET 4 Client Profile i got this Exception:

```
MissingMethodException:
Constructor on type 'Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeRegistryHandle' not found.
```

Exception occurred on return statement of this function:

```
private static SafeHandle CreateRegistrySafeHandle(IntPtr handle)
{
    Type type;

    type = typeof(SafeHandle).Assembly.GetType("Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeRegistryHandle");

    return (SafeHandle)Activator.CreateInstance(
        type,
        BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
        null,
        new object[] { handle, true },
        null);
}
```

**What is solution for this exception?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [SafeRegistryHandle Constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.safehandles.saferegistryhandle.saferegistryhandle.aspx) is public ([BindingFlags.Public](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx)) since .NET 4, not internal or private ([BindingFlags.NonPublic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx)).

If you have access to the source code, you can replace the method with

```
private static SafeHandle CreateRegistrySafeHandle(IntPtr handle)
{
    return new SafeRegistryHandle(handle, true);
}
```

Comment: I changed to `BindingFlags.Public` but still have this Exception!

Comment: After changing `BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic` to `BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public` it works on my machine.

Comment: Sorry! My fault! another same exception occurred for `RegistryKey`: `Constructor on type 'Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey' not found.` :P